# Count purchases from 2nd Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I think i just don't see the forest in cause of all the trees....

a) Two Tables:

- User (ID, UserName,...)
- Purchases (ID, UserID, ItemID,....)

b) I want a query which shows me how many purchases every user has made..

c) this query:

```
SELECT user.*, COUNT(purchases.userid) AS Purchases  
FROM user, purchases  
WHERE user.id=purchases.user_id
```

gives me only one result... and how to get the 0 if user hasn't made a purchase?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.ID, 
       u.UserName, 
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Purchases p WHERE u.Id=p.User_Id) AS Purchases
FROM User u
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like This:-

```
SELECT user.UserName, ISNULL(COUNT(purchases.userid),0) 
    AS Purchases1 FROM user AS user LEFT JOIN purchases AS purchases
    ON user.id=purchases.user_id
    Group by UserName
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` needs an `ON`, not `WHERE`

Comment: And you don't really need the `ISNULL()`.